# Sort array by name

Tags: php, sorting

I have got a multidimensional array :

```
[everything_list] => Array
        (
            [follow] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [username] => 3333
                            [username_image] => qykhgz4861sna14af6h6mpage_f4a.jpg
                            [follow_username] => 6666
                            [follow_image] => flw3utn9igiqh7dtt2o61ydf8_174.jpeg
                            [date] => 1329183703
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [username] => 3333
                            [username_image] => qykhgz4861sna14af6h6mpage_f4a.jpg
                            [follow_username] => 8888
                            [follow_image] => nsm5rixy14lexm9cy15wzyg9u_224.jpg
                            [date] => 1329168868
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [username] => 6666
                            [username_image] => flw3utn9igiqh7dtt2o61ydf8_174.jpeg
                            [follow_username] => 8888
                            [follow_image] => nsm5rixy14lexm9cy15wzyg9u_224.jpg
                            [date] => 1328221789
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [username] => 8888
                            [username_image] => nsm5rixy14lexm9cy15wzyg9u_224.jpg
                            [follow_username] => 6666
                            [follow_image] => flw3utn9igiqh7dtt2o61ydf8_174.jpeg
                            [date] => 1328219453
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [username] => 8888
                            [username_image] => nsm5rixy14lexm9cy15wzyg9u_224.jpg
                            [follow_username] => Kolxoznik1
                            [follow_image] => 
                            [date] => 1328218207
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [username] => 8888
                            [username_image] => nsm5rixy14lexm9cy15wzyg9u_224.jpg
                            [follow_username] => 3333
                            [follow_image] => qykhgz4861sna14af6h6mpage_f4a.jpg
                            [date] => 1328217742
                        )

                )

            [pictures] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [user] => 8888
                            [user_image] => nsm5rixy14lexm9cy15wzyg9u_224.jpg
                            [image] => nsm5rixy14lexm9cy15wzyg9u_224.jpg
                            [image_id] => 5
                            [text] => 
                            [date] => 1329072315
                            [comments] => 2
                            [first_image_id] => 4
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [user] => 8888
                            [user_image] => nsm5rixy14lexm9cy15wzyg9u_224.jpg
                            [image] => 0j1kjjzdv3ez07a0ee4lnmjb7_163.jpeg
                            [image_id] => 4
                            [text] => 
                            [date] => 1328577934
                            [comments] => 0
                            [first_image_id] => 4
                        )

                )
```

I want to sort this array by date and get something like :

```
[follow] => Array
{
....
}
[pictures] => Array
{
....
}
[follow] => Array
{
....
}
```

Comment: What have you tried with `usort()` so far?  http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [Sorting a multidimensional array](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=71904) hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly, something like this should do it

```
function orderByDate($a, $b)
{
    return $a['date'] < $b['date'];
}

$newArray = $array['everything_list']['follow'] + $array['everything_list']['pictures'];
usort($newArray, 'orderByDate');
```